# sliderButton.offset().left and event.pageX are completely different

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a button which I want to be able to drag left and right with mouse (similar to slider). The problem is, when I print out left offset of the button at page load and on mousedown (so when user clicks on the button), I get different results:

```
$(function() {
    var sliderButton = $('.slider-button');
    var initialLeft = sliderButton.offset().left;
    alert(initialLeft); // This returns 810
    var maximumLeft = initialLeft + 235;
    sliderButton.mousedown(function(e) {
        alert(e.pageX); // 576
        sliderButton.bind('mousemove', function(e) {
            var left = e.pageX;
            if (left >= initialLeft && left <= maximumLeft) {
                sliderButton.offset({left: left});
            }
        })
    }).bind('mouseup', function() {
        sliderButton.unbind('mousemove');
    });
});
```

First alert returns:

```
810
```

Second one:

```
576
```

On the mousedown event the cursor is at the same position as the button so shouldn't it return 810 as well? I don't get this behaviour.

Comment: Is this browser-specific?

Comment: I am using Chrome. Haven't tested in other browsers yet.

Comment: weird, it's working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Tezv2/.

Comment: I'm assuming that the HTML or CSS might have something to do with it as that code seems to work fine on multiple browsers.